# Controlling multiple arduinos from a pi 3b+

Tags: usb, pi-3b+, serial, arduino

I'm working on a robotics project where we need to control 2 motors, read data from 8 ultrasonic sensors, display a 2 digit number on 7 segment displays, drive servos and a few more things.

The initial plan was to have a master arduino that controls other arduinos, this way sensor data could be read much faster, servo could act more quickly etc, and have a raspberry pi that controlls the motors and does high level computations such as path planning etc.

There is a huge flaw in that however. The raspberry pi seems to miss interrupts from the rotary encoders attached to the motors. Our first test was using hard code timing and doing something like this:

```
motor.move(speed)
time.sleep(t)
motor.stop()
```

this worked ok and the wheels stopped after the given time. then I changed the code to use the rotary encoder pulses:

```
motor.move(speed)
while count < pulses:
    pass
motor.stop()
```

this way I'm busy waiting until a certain number of pulses is reached before stopping. Running this code resulted in many different results and after printing the trigger points of the interrupts, I noticed they were still coming in after the wheel had stopped which to me seems like an scheduler thing.

With that out of the question, we decided to use one arduino per wheel as motor drivers and control them via USB serial, but that introduces a new issue: how can I communicate with 2 arduinos at the same time? it's not very useful if one wheel turns all the way, stops, then the other wheel starts after that.

I was thinking something among the lines of multi processing? but then where should I use the join statement? I want the ports to never close during the match since connecting to the serial port, automatically restarts the arduino.

Would it be better to choose a different communication protocol than usb?

Comment: Personally I'd spend the effort on getting the rotary encoder to work on the Pi.  Using 8 sonar rangers probably isn't an optimum approach to object detection.

Comment: and how would I do that exactly when the OS scheduler is delaying interrupts?

Comment: You have given no evidence that it is.  Perhaps some code and some idea of how many interrupts per second you are talking about.

Comment: pisted an answer as "evidence"